# Give permissions to a specific role to edit specific terms

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary (*Foods*) with these terms.

- Meet
- Fruits

I want every user with the *Gardner* role to be able to edit the description of *Fruits* only. How can I do that?

This is just an example, on my site I have several terms, and I need specific users roles to edit specific term descriptions.

https://www.drupal.org/project/private_taxonomy does what I need, but I already have the taxonomy terms and I don't know how to change the ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access callback for a term edit page is [`taxonomy_term_edit_access($term)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_edit_access/7.x). You need to replace it with a custom one in order to allow gardeners to access the page for fruit terms.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['access callback']
    = 'MODULE_term_edit_access';
}

/**
 * Access callback for taxonomy edit term page.
 */
public function MODULE_term_edit_access($term) {
  if (MODULE_term_is_fruit($term) && user_access('edit fruits terms')) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return taxonomy_term_edit_access($term);
}

/**
 * Returns whether or not a term is a fruit.
 */
function MODULE_term_is_fruit($term) {
  // ... implement fruit detection here ...
  foreach (taxonomy_get_parents_all($term->tid) as $parent) {
    if ($parent->name == 'Fruit') {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE.
}

/**
 * Implement hook_permissions().
 */
function MODULE_permissions() {
  $permissions['edit fruits terms'] = array(
      'title' => t('Edit fruits terms'),
      'description' => t('Allows the user to edit Fruits terms.'),
  );
}
```

Comment: Unless you have tight control over the enabled modules, you can't be sure the original access callback (before `MODULE_menu_alter`) is `taxonomy_term_edit_access`. A more robust solution would be to start with to `$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['access arguments'][] = $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['access callback']` to keep a reference to the original callback. Then, at the end of `MODULE_term_edit_access($term)` you can do something like `$args = func_get_args(); return call_user_func(array_pop($args), $args);` to invoke it.